# gitignore include subdirectory in ignored directory not working

Tags: gitignore

I am trying to add an exemption to exclude the "img" and "fonts" folders under site/assets/ directories in my gitignore. See example below:

```
!site/
site/*
site/assets/*
!site/assets/img/
!site/assets/fonts/
```

I am running git version 2.6.4 on OS X Yosemite. None of the examples on stack overflow seems to work with my dilemma. Any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
site/**
!site/**/
!site/assets/img/**
!site/assets/fonts/**
```